# Accessing pointers in LuaTeX

Tags: luatex, discretionary

This code writes the subtype of disc nodes to the log file.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\directlua{
show_hyph = function(head)
  while head do
    if head.id == 0 or head.id == 1 then % hlist, vlist
      show_hyph(head.head)
    elseif head.id == 7 then             % disc
      texio.write_nl("Subtype " .. head.subtype)
    end
  head = head.next
  end
  return true
end
luatexbase.add_to_callback("post_linebreak_filter",show_hyph,"show_hyph")

}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{1pt}
  discretionary
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

The LuaTeX reference manual says in section 8.1.2.7 “disc nodes”

> `pre` `<node>` pointer to the pre-break text

How do I access this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How do I access this?

This is very simple and straightforward: use `head.pre` to access the list pointing to the *pre* part of the discretionary.

Now the question you might ask next is "why is the pre-part nil?" This is because you call your function `show_hyph()` on the *post*_linebreak_filter. At that point the *pre* part is already inserted before that disc node and thus the *pre* part is empty. The same is with *post* and *replace*. What I can't tell you is why the disc node stays in the node list.

Comment: OK. I was hoping to use this to review the hyphenations, but it seems it is not that simple.

Comment: @HåkonMalmedal Just ask another question on "how to review ... " and I'll think of a solution :)