# Reviewing hyphenations with LuaTeX

Tags: luatex, hyphenation

> **This question led to a new package:**
>   [`lua-check-hyphen`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lua-check-hyphen)

I wrote a question ([Accessing pointers in LuaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60421/4771)) hoping it would lead me to a way of reviewing the hyphenations with LuaTeX, and without external programs. I was encouraged to write this question.

The answers to the question “[Check all hyphenations within a document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14063/4771)” point to external tools.

I’m hoping for a solution which writes the hyphenation to the log file everytime a word is split across two lines, for easy reviewing.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

### Update:

The package is now also on [CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/) and dwells at:
http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lua-check-hyphen

---

There is a new experimental package for that purpose: `lua-check-hyphen` which you can download here: https://github.com/pgundlach/lua-check-hyphen (copy the `.sty` and the `.lua` file into the current directory). This will list the hyphenated words in a separate file (ending with `.uhy`) and has the ability to create a whitelist with "good" hyphenations and you can optionally mark unknown hyphenations.

Consider this input file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[mark]{lua-check-hyphen}

\begin{document}

\hsize 1.3in
A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet
mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart.

\end{document}
```

which results in

[image: image with boxes]

and a file `test.uhy` with this content:

```
seren-ity
posses-sion
morn-ings
```

Now you can add these lines (if you believe that they are valid breakpoints) to a textfile for example called `okhyph.txt` and add this to the command `LuaCheckHyphen`. Let's put the second line into that file and use it in the document:

```
\begin{filecontents}{okhyph.txt}
posses-sion
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[mark]{lua-check-hyphen}
\LuaCheckHyphen{whitelist=okhyph.txt}

\begin{document}

\hsize 1.3in
A wonderful serenity has taken possession of my entire soul, like these sweet
mornings of spring which I enjoy with my whole heart.

\end{document}
```

Now lua-check-hyphen does not complain about that word anymore.

[image]

And the file `test.uhy` now contains only:

```
morn-ings
seren-ity
```

You can continue until you have a clean document. If you pass the option `final` to the package, no hyphenation checking is done.

Comment: If the hyphenated word contains a ligature, the ligature is written to the file, e.g. `ﬀ` (U+FB00 LATIN SMALL LIGATURE FF). A tt ligature is not written.

Comment: @HåkonMalmedal This should be fixed now.

Comment: Patrick: this package look great, I wrote about it on my blog, so that more people can be aware of it!

Comment: @mbork great! Next version will have a "nofile" option which prevents the software from writing an external file.

Comment: @PatrickGundlach: good idea, especially that there are quite a few questions here about TeX cluttering people's disks with strange files;).

Answer (score 14):

(I updated this answer in response to a comment by user @Guest, informing me that the `showhyphens` package is obsolete and that the `showhyphenation` package might be used instead.)

Since you're using Lua(La)TeX, you may want to consider employing the nifty [showhyphenation](https://ctan.org/pkg/showhyphenation) package. As its name suggests, this package shows *all* hyphenation points that TeX considers to be valid, whether or not hyphenation actually occurs or not. While this package doesn't perform precisely the task you're trying to accomplish, I believe that its output is actually *even more useful* than what you're after: Not only does it tell you where hyphenations occur but it also alerts you to (i) potentially invalid hyphenation points and (ii) hyphenation points that TeX might miss entirely.

Taking your three-paragraph question as an example, a simple MWE using this package might look like this:

```
% !TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec,showhyphenation}

\begin{document}
I wrote a question (Accessing pointers in LuaTeX) hoping it would 
lead me to a way of reviewing the hyphenations with LuaTeX, and 
without external programs. I was encouraged to write this question.

The answers to the question ``Check all hyphenations within a document'' 
point to external tools.

I'm hoping for a solution which writes the hyphenation to the log file 
everytime a word is split across two lines, for easy reviewing.
\end{document}
```

and would produce the following output:

[image]

Even though this short text contains only one hyphenated word, the little red markers show one incorrect hyphenation point (Lu-a-TeX) and one missed hyphenation point (in the word `hyphenation`, and in that word's plural form). To fix these issues, it suffices to insert the command

```
\hyphenation{Lua-TeX hy-phen-a-tion hy-phen-a-tions}
```

in the preamble of the MWE, leading to the following, more satisfactory output:

[image]

Of course, TeX's hyphenation algorithm isn't perfect (nor does anyone claim that it is!), so for "real" production work you should probably want to load a custom hyphenation exception list to treat words that you (or others) have noticed in the past are not hyphenated properly. One such list, aimed at US English documents, is in the file [ushyphex.tex](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/digests/tugboat/hyphenex/ushyphex.tex) that's available on the CTAN; it contains (as of December 2022) about 1750 words. Of course, the recommendation to employ suitable hyphenation exception lists applies to other languages as well, not just to (US) English.

Comment: +1 for finding that "hyphenation" isn't fully hyphenated.  into the exceptions list it goes.

Comment: Off-topic, I noticed that your images are always of poor resolution, now I just realised they are poorly scaled by the browser, so may be you would consider generating them at smaller size by default (width of 800px or 600px I think).

Comment: @KhaledHosny -- Many thanks for this. I'll try to figure out what's going on and (most likely!) change the size per your suggestion.

Comment: The package `showhyphens` is marked as `obsolete` the code does not compile anymore, an alternative is `\usepackage{showhyphenation}`

Comment: @Guest - Many thanks for bringing the fact the `showhyphens` package has become obsolete to my attention. I've updated my answer to follow your suggestion to employ the [showhypenation](https://ctan.org/pkg/showhyphenation) package instead.

Answer (score 10):

A slightly more complex answer: This solution collects all possible hyphen points before it breaks the paragraph into lines, after the paragraph is broken into lines it checks again which of these hyphenation have really been used. These are collected in a table and at the end of the document these words are printed to the log file (and to the LuaTeX run).

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage{luaotfload}
\usepackage[EU2]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{luacode}
\usepackage{luatexbase-attr}

\AtEndDocument{\directlua{listhyphenatedwords()}}
\begin{document}

\begin{luacode*}

local hyphenattr =  luatexbase.new_attribute("hyphenattr")
do
  local hyphenwords = {}
  local all_hyphenatedwords = {}

  function collect_discs (head)
    local word_start
    local word
    -- this is where we store all the breakpoints
    local thisbreakpoint
    local word_with_hyphen
    local c
    local hyphencounter = #hyphenwords + 1
    local sln = unicode.utf8

    while head do
      if head.id == 0 then
      elseif head.id == 7 then --disc
        word_start = head
        word_end   = head
        while word_start.prev and word_start.prev.id ~= 10 do
          word_start = word_start.prev
        end
        word = ""
        c = 0
        while word_start and word_start.id ~= 10 do
          if word_start == head then -- disc
            -- there is a breakpoint after letter c
            node.set_attribute(head,hyphenattr,hyphencounter)
            thisbreakpoint = c
          elseif word_start.id == 37 then
            c = c + 1
            if sln.match(sln.char(word_start.char),"%a") then
              word = word .. sln.char(word_start.char)
            end
          end
          word_start = word_start.next
        end
        word_with_hyphen = sln.sub(word,1,thisbreakpoint) .. "-" .. sln.sub(word,thisbreakpoint+1,-1)
        hyphenwords[hyphencounter] = word_with_hyphen
        hyphencounter = #hyphenwords + 1
      end
      head = head.next
    end
    return true
  end

  function check_discs(head)
    local c
    while head do
      if head.id < 2 then
        check_discs(head.list)
      elseif head.id == 7 and head.next and head.next.id == 10 then -- disc
        c = node.has_attribute(head,hyphenattr)
        all_hyphenatedwords[#all_hyphenatedwords + 1] = hyphenwords[c]
      end
      head = head.next
    end
    return true
  end

  function listhyphenatedwords()
    texio.write_nl("All hyphenated words follow:")
    for i in ipairs(all_hyphenatedwords) do
      texio.write_nl(all_hyphenatedwords[i])
    end
    texio.write_nl("All hyphenated words above.")
  end
end



luatexbase.add_to_callback("pre_linebreak_filter",collect_discs,"collect_discs")
luatexbase.add_to_callback("post_linebreak_filter",check_discs,"check_discs")
\end{luacode*}
\hsize 2in

Seit zwei Jahren ist meine Arbeit in Düsseldorf. Meine Familie lebt dagegen in
Hamburg. Und dazwischen ich, aber ganz cool. Vollbremskombination aus Ampel
oder Einfädeln oder beides auf einmal. Geht nur mit Tricks. Eben noch kurz auf
die A 52. Schon vielversprechend lebhaft. Hinter dem Breitscheider Kreuz geht
es richtig los. Stau auf der A 3 bis Oberhausen. Danach entspannt es sich auch
nur deshalb, weil enge Baustellen mit rüden Geschwindigkeitsbegrenzungen zum
gleichmäßigen Rollen zwingen. Es wird links überholt, es wird rechts überholt.
Es wird gar nichts mehr, alles steht und macht lange Gesichter. Ich dagegen
wechsle die Cassette.


Es geht weiter. Vor und hinter mir hektische Spurenwechsel. So zieht sich das
Stück A 2 bis zum Recklinghauser Kreuz. Der erhofften Entspannung folgt
zuverlässig der Vollfrust. Die A 43 bis Münster ist genauso voll wie das
Kamener Kreuz zur Rush-hour.

\end{document}
```

gives:

```
...
All hyphenated words follow:
Ar-beit
Fami-lie
ein-mal
rich-tig
Ober-hausen
Bau-stellen
Geschwindigkeits-begrenzungen
über-holt
hin-ter
zu-verlässig
All hyphenated words above. [1
...
```

which is in accordance to the output file:

[image: hyphenated text]

Comment: The next step would be to have a word list of "correct" hyphenation points and only output / mark in the output the unknown hyphenation points.

Comment: Wow, this is a lot more sophisticated than the answer I came up with! It also really shows the power and versatility of lua as a scripting language.