# German hyphenation does not work

Tags: babel, hyphenation, classicthesis, german

My *babel* configuration includes *ngerman* and *english* ...

```
\documentclass[
oneside, openright, titlepage,
dottedtoc, numbers=noenddot,
headinclude, footinclude=true,
cleardoublepage=empty, abstractoff,
BCOR=5mm, paper=a4, fontsize=11pt,
ngerman,
american,
draft
]
{scrreprt}

\PassOptionsToPackage{utf8}{inputenc}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage[pdfspacing]{classicthesis}

\begin{document}

% Disable paragraph indentation.
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

9. Wie lange benötigen die Personen für die Erfassung/Aktualisierung
der Daten vor Ort und bei der Nachbearbeitung im Büro?\\

10. Verwenden Sie ein kommerzielles Hardware- oder Software-Produkt
für die Verwaltung\\

\end{document}
```

..., however, the hyphenation seems to be not working correctly, as I can see in *draft* mode.

[image: German hypenation]

**Questions:**

- What do I need to configure in order to use auto-hyphenation?
- Side question: Why do I need to add `\\` to get an empty line between `9.` and `10.`?

Comment: Use `"~` for dashes or `"=`. And `/""...` for the `/`.  See the documentation of [babel](http://texdoc.net/pkg/babel)

Comment: Use `\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}`. Unless you say `\selectlanguage` later the last language in the option list is active.

Comment: Also words with dashes hyphens like `Software-Produkt` will only be hyphenated at the dash unless you follow @PatrickGundlach's advice and write `Software"=Produkt`.

Comment: Just in case you use LuaTeX: see the answers to the following question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60435/243

Comment: You may also want to use `\slash` instead of the `/` symbol; this tells LaTeX that it's OK to break the long "word" `Erfassung/Aktualisierung` after the slash.

Comment: When I add `"-` the word gets hyphenated but still the `"` gets printed.

Comment: @PatrickGundlach When I add `"=` both characters get printed but no hyphenation happens. When I use `"~` a `" ` gets printed and no hyphenation applies.

Comment: @cgnieder Nice hint, no changes regarding the hyphenation though.

Comment: @Mico There is still no hyphenation when I use `Erfassung\slash Aktualisierung`.

Comment: @JJD these shorthands are only active with the (n)german language. Pass only the ngerman to babel or use `\selectlanguage{ngerman}` in order to use the shorthands.

Comment: What is the “\PassOptionsToPackage{utf8}{inputenc}\usepackage{inputenc}” good for? ´\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}´ works fine!

Comment: @Speravir Sorry, this is a fragment from an older setup. I did not clean the configuration. Thx for the advice.

Comment: @JJD: I think there are two separate issues here: First, because you haven't set "german" (or "ngerman") as the *last-named* language, German hyphenation rules aren't in effect. Second, use of `\slash` instead of `/` only serves to tell LaTeX that the preceding and following words are distinct (instead of one very long and complicated word); use of `\slash` by itself won't enable German-language hyphenation rules.

Comment: Another addition: I think, actually your problem is, that you already declared languages in the documentclass options. And once again: If you mostly want to use German in your document, you should change the order in the babel _or_ (exclusive or) documentclass options – what Patrick said: Read the babel documentation.

Comment: @Mico I also couldn't get `\slash` to work (and I made sure `ngerman` hyphenation was enabled). Not sure why...

Comment: Alternatively you could add another shorthand by saying `\makeatletter\declare@shorthand{ngerman}{"/}{\penalty\@M/\hskip\z@skip}\makeatother` and then use `Erfassung"/Aktualisierung`

Comment: @Speravir I ended up with the following: `\documentclass[ngerman]`,  `\usepackage{babel}` and **without** `\selectlanguage{ngerman}`. I think, a lot of my *not working* experience came from the fact that I need to run *PDFLaTeX* **more than once**.

Comment: @cgnieder - I think there's some kind of interaction I hadn't noticed before between babel (and the ngerman option) and the `\slash` command, which disables hyphenation after `\slash`. Fortunately, `\slash\hspace{0pt}` still works, but it's not nearly as elegant!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to select the language that is used.  So add `\selectlanguage{ngerman}` in front of German text and `\selectlanguage{english}`in front of english text.

The hyphenation is not working because LaTeX has problems to hyphenate `Erfassung/Aktualisierung`  correctly. Insert (you are using `babel`) `"-` to mark the places a hyphenation can occur.

Use `\begin{enumerate}` to build well typesetted enumerations.

I added these thing in your MWE:

```
\documentclass[
oneside, openright, titlepage,
dottedtoc, numbers=noenddot,
headinclude, footinclude=true,
cleardoublepage=empty, abstractoff,
BCOR=5mm, paper=a4, fontsize=11pt,
ngerman,
american,
draft
]
{scrreprt}

\PassOptionsToPackage{utf8}{inputenc}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage[pdfspacing]{classicthesis}

\begin{document}

% Disable paragraph indentation.
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Wie lange benötigen die Personen für die Erfassung/Aktuali"-sierung 
    der Daten vor Ort und bei der Nachbearbeitung im Büro?
  \item Verwenden Sie ein kommerzielles Hardware- oder Software-Produkt
    für die Verwaltung
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @JJD when you remove the american/ngerman from the global option list, you can see the differences in the order for babel by using the `"=` and similar shorthands.

Comment: @PatrickGundlach When I use `\usepackage{babel}` with `\selectlanguage{ngerman}` and put `"=` or `"-` it still works. Sorry for my confusion.

Comment: And I thought German didn't hyphenate because those Germans (I am one culturally, too) much prefer the look of Verylongcompoundwordswithouthyphenationjusttoconfusethefrench.  Silly me.