# Why is Latex hyphenating some words automatically, but others dont?

Tags: babel, hyphenation, debugging, badness

On this example, the word `usando` is not being hyphenated, but the word `Comandos` is. If I force a hyphen on the first word `usan-do`, it is hyphenated correctly:

```
\documentclass[10pt,openright,twoside,a5paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{1.6cm}

\begin{document}

\frenchspacing
\selectlanguage{brazil}
No entanto, você pode compilar os documentos \LaTeX usando os seguintes
comandos, que devem ser digitados no \emph{Prompt de Comandos} do Windows ou no
\emph{Terminal} do Mac ou do Linux:

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
test2.tex:11: Overfull \hbox (4.94724pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 11--14[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 No en-tanto, voc pode com-pi-lar os do-cu-men-tos L[]T[]Xusando
```

Is there some way to debug the LaTeX hyphenation? For example, I can debug the overfull boxes, using `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}` or `\usepackage{showframe}` in my preamble. So, is there some package I can include which helps me to find out why LaTeX is not hyphenating some words?

---

Related questions:

1. [LaTeX Hyphenation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33214/latex-hyphenation)
2. [German hyphenation does not work](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/68293/german-hyphenation-does-not-work)
3. [How to prevent LaTeX from hyphenating the entire document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5036/how-to-prevent-latex-from-hyphenating-the-entire-document)

Comment: the word at the end of the first sentence is "\LaTeX usando", not just "usando" and (la)tex will never hyphenate a word that incorporates a control sequence.

Comment: @barbarabeeton as written this isn't true, is it? Of course TeX will hyphenate words with control sequences in it (as long as those resolve simply to characters in the current font). The reason that it doesn't hyphenate \LaTeX adds kerns and boxes etc

Comment: @FrankMittelbach -- er, maybe it isn't strictly true, but i prefer the simpler approach.  i just make the rash assumption that there's no break between `\LaTeX` and what follows, so tex considers it to be a unit.  probably it *is* because of kerns and boxes (and that would be true too of "`\TeX book`" which won't hyphenate either unless one tells it to with a control sequence definition).  also, remember that i'm still working mostly within an ot1 environment.

Comment: @barbarabeeton OT1 is the key, but if you are not typing in English then you often have diacritics. And if you type them as commands, e.g., Gl\"uhw\"urmchen then this hyphenates perfectly (in T1). So at least for languages like German commands have been common  inside words in the last 20+ years (only now with utf8 they start to become less).

Comment: @FrankMittelbach -- i do like your example.  (reminds me that i miss fireflies here in new england.  they used to be everywhere in the summer when i was a kid in baltimore.)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

At first the word `\LaTeX` right before `usando` is confusing the hyphenation. But most importantly: \righthyphenmin is 3 in this language, that means that LaTeX will never break 2 chars at the end. You can change this:

```
\documentclass[10pt,openright,twoside,a5paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{1.6cm}

\renewcommand\brazilhyphenmins{22} %left=2, right=2

\begin{document}

\frenchspacing
\selectlanguage{brazil}
No entanto, você pode compilar os documentos \LaTeX{} usando os seguintes
comandos, que devem ser digitados no \emph{Prompt de Comandos} do Windows ou no
\emph{Terminal} do Mac ou do Linux:

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! But it seems it is another problem other than the `\brazilhyphenmins` with the word `usando`. Even after adding it, it still does not hyphenate it. I even tried using `\brazilhyphenmins{11}`, only forcing it with `usan-do` hyphenates it.

Comment: As I wrote: The \LaTeX is problematic too, that's why I added {} and a space after the command.

Comment: Sorry, Now you said so, I understand. When you said `\Latex` I though you were talking about the Latex language itself, not the word `\Latex` which comes right before `usando`.

Answer (score 6):

Ulrike's answer is right, of course, but such problems can often be prevented by loading the `microtype` package.  Here that gets

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt,openright,twoside,a5paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}

\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\setlength{\parindent}{1.6cm}


\begin{document}

\frenchspacing
\selectlanguage{brazil}
No entanto, você pode compilar os documentos \LaTeX{}  usando os seguintes
comandos, que devem ser digitados no \emph{Prompt de Comandos} do Windows ou no
\emph{Terminal} do Mac ou do Linux:

\end{document}
```

*EDIT*

What microtype does is play with all sorts of typographical features to make words fit better on a line and to make the end of the line look more even.  It's clear that it helps here.

Comment: An explanation of why, and what the package does, would be great.

Comment: Have done......

Comment: but here, `\LaTeX` is explicitly terminated with `{}`, so it's not at all the same as `\LaTeX usando`, which was the original condition.  microtype wouldn't help that, i don't think.

Comment: That is true, though even then it mitigates (but does not completely address) the problem.

Comment: Wish i knew about `microtype` sooner!