# Why add a slash after each command on text as \latex?

Tags: macros, tex-core

On the question [Why Latex is hyphenating some words automatically, but others dont?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/387076/why-latex-is-hyphenating-some-words-automatically-but-others-dont) I learned I need to add `{}` (may be also `\relax`) every time I use a text command like `\latex` to print the the word LaTeX nicely and keep the correct text hyphenation.

But while fixing my document template accordingly to the hyphenation rules, I found several commands appended with a single backslash as in:

```
criadas sequencialmente, o \abnTeX\ instrui o \LaTeX\ para que uma vírgula seja
```

Why they were appending a backslash on it? Can I still fix the hyphenation with `\latex{}\` or I should use only `\latex{}` or perhaps `\latex\relax` [What is the difference between \relax and {}?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86385/what-is-the-difference-between-relax-and)

Comment: The single backslash followed by a space (`\ `) is a guaranteed space in output.

Comment: Thanks @Skillmon! It seems then there is no need for adding ``\latex\`` on the text, so I can just replace them with `\latex{}`. But why would they want to force a space after with `\ `?

Comment: `\ ` is faster to type.

Comment: So I just tested, I can use `\ ` and `{}` to fix the hyphenation.

Comment: You need something to get a space between the two words (regardless of hyphenation youdontwritewithoutspaces). Both `\LaTeX{} ` and `\LaTeX\ ` will work for this.  It is here only a matter of taste and typing habits which one you chose.

Comment: I always favoured `{\latex}` myself. Not sure why. Perhaps it looks less artificial than the alternatives.

Comment: More links : [Space after LaTeX commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31091/space-after-latex-commands) and [Drawbacks of xspace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86565/drawbacks-of-xspace)

Comment: this is unrelated to hyphenation or abnt