# Warn of long words without a hyphenation pattern?

Tags: hyphenation

For unusual words, is there a quick way to check if I must specify my own hyphenation pattern?

In this example, the word 'cacheability' needs a custom pattern.  I do not want to scan my document looking for the problem words jutting into the margin.  Currently, I provide a hyphenation for every long word my editor flags for spell checking, but it's a pain.

I'd really like a package that warns me of long words without a hyphenation pattern.

```
\documentclass{book}
%\hyphenation{ cache-abil-ity }
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
cacheability cacheability cacheability cacheability cacheability cacheability cacheability cacheability cacheability cacheability cacheability cacheability cacheability cacheability cacheability cacheability.
\end{document}
```

Comment: The answer is very short: no.

Comment: Maybe you can use the `showhyphens` package as a basis for finding long words without hyphenation points? See [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55509/12850) or maybe [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60435/12850).

Comment: If I can load existing hyphenation patters into a lua table, is there a hook to let lua check each word as it goes by?  Is this better as a distinct question on stackexchange?

Comment: You may also want to check the `\hfuzz` parameter to suppress warnings of really small distortions.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think there is a package for it, but maybe I also don't really get your point.

If LaTeX cannot hyphenate some word, it will let you know with a *bad Box* warning. If you keep track of your errors, warnings and badboxes (you should do this at least once -- right before you have your document finished for printing), then you will see if there is some hyphenation pattern missing. By taking a look at the corresponding badbox message in the log you can also see, where exactly the problem lies, because it prints the last words of a line where the linebreaking algorithm was forced to break the line.

Try to compile the following MWE and look at the logfile:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
This is some random text to show a word that cannot be hyphenated cacheability
\end{document}
```

It will give you the following badbox warning

*Overfull \hbox (6.11166pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 4--5
[]\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 This is some ran-dom text to show a word that can-not be hy-p
hen-ated cacheabil-
 []*

If this is not enough for you, you can also set the `draft` option to your documentclass which will draw a highly visible black bar at the end of every line where a overfull box appears.

The things described before only notify you when hyphenation is really needed and are no general automatism. But unfortunately I don't think there's an automatic way to remind you of every word that has no hyphenation pattern defined.